# web2py d3.json() where to put the json file?

Tags: d3.js, web2py

I'm trying to use [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045#miserables.json) sample code.

My question is for this line : `d3.json("miserables.json", function(error, graph){}`

Where should I put the miserables.json file?

My d3.js is in static/js/d3.py

Should I just put the file under static/js?

I have tried this, but all I got is a blank page.

I'm not familiar with how path works for d3.json()

My html file:

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
 <div id="vi"></div>
<style>

.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: .6;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(30)
    .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.select("#vi").json("miserables.json", function(error, graph) {
  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(force.drag);

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  });
});

</script>
<p>k<p>
```

This  `response.files.append(URL('static', 'plugin_d3/d3/d3.js'))` is in my function code already. And there's an copy of the json code under static/plugin_d3/d3 also!

Please bear me for this simple question.

Thanks!!

Comment: `d3.select("#vi").json("miserables.json", function(error, graph) {` should be just `d3.json("mise...`? And put the `miserables.json` file on the same path which is serving the `index.html`. I am not familiar with web2py, so I am afraid cannot give you concrete code.

Comment: @musically_ut I did what you said, but it still does not work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can put miserable.json in the /static folder (perhaps in a subfolder within /static). You then have to use the correct URL to refer to it. Given that you code is in a web2py template, you can use the `URL()` function to generate the URL:

```
d3.select("#vi").json("{{=URL('static', 'miserables.json')}}", ...)
```

In your original code:

```
d3.select("#vi").json("miserables.json", ...)
```

"miserable.json" is a relative URL, so the browser will just append that to the URL of the current page, which would end up being something like /yourapp/default/index/miserables.json. Instead, you need to specify the full URL, such as /yourapp/static/miserables.json (which the `URL()` function will generate).

Comment: I tried what you said, but it seems it still could not access to the file. In my html, I tried <div>{{=open(URL('static', 'miserables.json'))}}</div> to test if it could access to the file, but I get <type 'exceptions.IOError'> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/testD3/static/miserables.json' But I'm pretty sure I have a copy of miserables.json under '/testD3/static/'. Thanks!

Comment: I could even visit the json file in my browser through:　http://localhost:8000/testD3/static/miserables.json

Comment: It works for the d3, even this: {{=open(URL('static', 'miserables.json'))}} some how doesn't work.  Thanks!!! I almost cry!!!

Comment: The Python `open()` function takes a file path on the filesystem, not a URL. Furthermore, if you want to read the content of the file, you have to call the `.read()` method. And finally, if you want to insert arbitrary code such as JSON into a web2py view without having it escaped, you have to wrap it in `XML()`. So, it would be `<div>{{=XML(open(os.path.join(request.folder, 'static', 'miserables.json'), 'r').read())}}</div>`.